# Tests for checking kerning and sidebearings

Tags: fonts, typography, kerning

To test the kerning and sidebearings of digital fonts, Bringhurst suggests the following methods:

- To check the sidebearings typeset consecutive pairs of letters and check the symmetry.
- For the kerning typeset the letter combinations.

He also shows a test text which shows the usual badly kerned combinations of letters.

Has someone prepared TeX files with such text that can be readily run for different fonts? and want to share them? :-)

Comment: It seems not, I'm afraid.

Comment: Possibly useful (perhaps?): http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kerntest

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks! I was not able to find it. I found a python script that generates the pairings. If I have some time I would like to publish something usefull in CTAN.

Comment: Perhaps the package `microtype` will help you. Is able to fix the microaesthetical issues in typography. But I'm not sure if it works with all the typefaces, and it seem you need to add the kerning table for the correct composition.

Comment: @zunbeltz If you found the answer to your own question, could you post your comment as an answer (even if it only points toward a full answer to your question)? It does not look like anyone else has done what you ask for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way to start with fontspec, [from an online kern text](http://www.as8.it/type/basic_kerning_text.html).
Just set the font you want, enter feature file if you have one and run the file for each desired variant (bold, small caps, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,url,microtype}


 \setmonofont
 %FeatureFile = if-you-have-it.fea,
 %SmallCapsFeatures = {LetterSpace  =  2.0}]
 {GFS Didot}% What you want


\begin{document}
From \url{http://www.as8.it/type/basic_kerning_text.html}
\bigskip

\begin{verbatim}


Basic Kerning Text



BASIC ALPHABET 


AÆBCÇDEFGH

IJKLMNOŒØP

QRSTUVWXYZ/\

aæbcçdefﬁﬂghijklm

noœøpqrstuvwxyz

1234567890

°’”$¢ƒß£¥%⁄#

&.,:;…·!?“”‘’

•- – —*„‚_|®©™

([{«»‹›}])

ˆ˜¯˘˙˚¸˝˛ˇ`´¨

†‡§¶@+=±


FOREIGN CHARS


ÄÅÂÁÀÃÇÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌ 

ÑÖÓÔÒÕÜÚÛÙŸ

áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñ

óòôöõúùûüÿ


Pi & OTHER/TEXT FONTS


_^|∏πΩ¬ªº¿¡

∆◊§∞µ∂∑€‰


SAMPLE KERNING PAIRS


AT AV AW AY Av Aw Ay 

Fa Fe Fo Kv Kw Ky LO 

LV LY PA Pa Pe Po TA 

Ta Te Ti To Tr Ts Tu Ty 

UA VA Va Ve Vo Vr Vu Vy 

WA WO Wa We Wr Wv Wy 


SAMPLE LOWERCASE

INCIDENTALS


w! w? f! f? ¡a ¿a

«n»«o»‹n›‹o›

h∂ho&o‚{h}h•h

o•oh@hªhº

h⁄h‚h„h™h®h©h

h·h o·o`´˘¨ˆ˜¯ˇ˙˚¸˝˛ˆ

h”h“h“w” 


h.h,h:h;‘h’

o.o,o:o;‘o’

(h)[h]h/h\h

(o)[o]h-ho-o

(h)[h]h/h\h#

(o)[o]h-ho-h

h£h$h¢hƒh¥h

h*h†h‡h§

h–ho–o

h—ho—o

h+h=h±h'h"h°h#h

h%h‰h…h

h1h2h3h4h5h0h

h6h7h8h9h0h

£110121314151

$16171819122

23242526¢

27282930%


SAMPLE SIDEBARING


HAHBHCHDHEHFHGHHH

HIHJHKHLHMHNHOHPHQH

HRHSHTHUHVHWHXHYHZH

HÆHŒHÄHÖHÜHÅHÇHÁH

HÛHÍHÏHÌHÓEHÙHØH&HaH

HbHcHdHeHfHgHhHiHjHvkH

HlHmHnHoHpHqHrHsHtHuH

HvHwHxHyHzHßHæHœHäH

HöHüHﬁHﬂHåHıHçHøH1H2H

H3H4H5H6H7H8H9H0H£H¢H

H$H¥HƒH!H¡H?H¿H*H#H/H+H

H=H÷H≠H±HvH∂H◊H≈H√H~HµH

H∞H.H,H;H:H”H”H”H‘H’H…H

H‹H›H»H«H[H]H(H)H{H}H⁄H–H

H‰H%H¶H|H’H™H®H©H•H@H

H˘HˆH`H´HˇH˜H¨H·H¸H¯H˚H˛H˝H˙H


SAMPLE TEXT


Think about it, your unique designs 

evaluated by experts in typography, 

fabulous prizes, recognition and the 

envy of your peers! Not only that, your 

work will be offered for sale around 

the world by the best alternative type 

foundry going. And that would be 

us...GarageFonts.


COMPARISONS


÷±≤≥–—≠<=>-+≈

([{«»‹›}])‰%¡¿!?

“”‘’°’”ˆ˜¯˘˙˚˝ˇ`´¨„‚.,:;…·

®©™@



ALL CAPS


AABACADAEAFAGAHAIAJAK

ALAMANAOAPAQARASATAU

AVAWAXAYAZA A’S A”

A-A–A—A…A. A, A; A: A? A!

BABBCBDBEBFBGBHBIBJBK

BLBMBNBOBPBQBRBSBTBU

BVBWBXBYBZB B’S B”

B-B–B—B…B. B, B; B: B? B!

CACBCCDCECFCGCHCICJCK

CLCMCNCOCPCQCRCSCTCU

CVCWCXCYCZC C’S C”

C-C–C—C…C. C, C; C: C? C!

DADBDCDDEDFDGDHDIDJDK

DLDMDNDODPDQDRDSDTDU

DVDWDXDYDZD D’S D”DØD

D-D–D—D…D. D, D; D: D? D!

EAEBECEDEEFEGEHEIEJEK

ELEMENEOEPEQERESETEU

EVEWEXEYEZE E’S E”

E-E–E—E…E. E, E; E: E? E!

FAFBFCFDFEFFGFHFIFJFK

FLFMFNFOFPFQFRFSFTFU

FVFWFXFYFZF F’S F”

F-F–F—F…F. F, F; F: F? F!

GAGBGCGDGEGFGGHGIGJGK

GLGMGNGOGPGQGRGSGTGU

GVGWGXGYGZG G’S G”

G-G–G—G…G. G, G; G: G? G!

HAHBHCHDHEHFHGHHIHJHK

HLHMHNHOHPHQHRHSHTHU

HVHWHXHYHZH H’S H”

H-H–H—H…H. H, H; H: H? H!

IAIBICIDIEIFIGIHIIJIK

ILIMINIOIPIQIRISITIUIVIWIXIYIZ

I’S I”I-I–I—I…I. I, I; I: I? I!

JAJBJCJDJEJFJGJHJIJJK

JLJMJNJOJPJQJRJSJTJU

JVJWJXJYJZJ J’S J”

J-J–J—J…J. J, J; J: J? J!

KAKBKCKDKEKFKGKHKIKJK

KLKMKNKOKPKQKRKSKTKU

KVKWKXKYKZK K’S K”

K-K–K—K…K. K, K; K: K? K!

LALBLCLDLELFLGLHLILJLK

LLMLNLOLPLQLRLSLTLU

LVLWLXLYLZL L’S L”

L-L–L—L…L. L, L; L: L?L

L!MAMBMCMDMEMFMGMHMIMJMK

MLMMNMOMPMQMRMSMTMU

MVMWMXMYMZM M’S M”

M-M–M—M…M. M, M; M: M? M!

NANBNCNDNENFNGNHNINJNK

NLNMNNNONPNQNRNSNTNU

NVNWNXNYNZN N’S N”

N-N–N—N…N. N, N; N: N? N!

OAOBOCODOEOFOGOHOIOJOK

OLOMONOOPOQOROSOTOU

OVOWOXOYOZO O’S O”

O-O–O—O…O. O, O; O: O? O!

PAPBPCPDPEPFPGPHPIPJPK

PLPMPNPOPPQPRPSPTPU

PVPWPXPYPZP P’S P”

P-P–PP—P…P. P, P; P: P? P!

QAQBQCQDQEQFQGQHQIQJQK

QLQMQNQOQPQQRQSQTQU

QVQWQXQYQZQ Q’S Q”

Q-Q–Q—Q…Q. Q, Q; Q: Q? Q!

RARBRCRDRERFRGRHRIRJRK

RLRMRNRORPRQRRSRTRU

RVRWRXRYRZR R’S R”

R-R–R—R…R. R, R; R: R? R!

SASBSCSDSESFSGSHSISJSK

SLSMSNSOSPSQSRSSTSU

SVSWSXSYSZS S’S S”

S-S–S—S…S. S, S; S: S? S!

TATBTCTDTETFTGTHTITJTK

TLTMTNTOTPTQTRTSTTU

TVTWTXTYTZT T’S T”

T-T–T—T…T. T, T; T: T? T!

UAUBUCUDUEUFUGUHUIUJUK

ULUMUNUOUPUQURUSUTUU

UVUWUXUYUZU U’S U”

U-U–U—U…U. U, U; U: U? U!

VAVBVCVDVEVFVGVHVIVJVK

VLVMVNVOVPVQVRVSVTVU

VVWVXVYVZV V’S V”

V-V–V—V…V. V, V; V: V? V!

WAWBWCWDWEWFWGWHWIWJWK

WLWMWNWOWPWQWRWSWTWU

WVWWXWYWZW W’S W”

W-W–W—W…W. W, W; W: W? W!

XAXBXCXDXEXFXGXHXXIXJXK

XLXMXNXOXPXQXRXSXTXU

XVXWXXYXZX X’S X”

X-X–X—X…X. X, X; X: X? X!

YAYBYCYDYEYFYGYHYIYJYK

YLYMYNYOYPYQYRYSYTYU

YVYWYXYYZY Y’S Y”

Y-Y–Y—Y…Y. Y, Y; Y: Y? Y!

ZAZBZCZDZEZFZGZHZIZJZK

ZLZMZNZOZPZQZRZSZTZU

ZVZWZXZYZZ Z’S Z”

Z-Z–Z—Z…Z. Z, Z; Z: Z? Z!


LOWER CASE


aabacadaeafagahaiajakalama

anaoapaqarasatauavawaxayaza

a…a. a, a; a: a! a? a-a–a—a’s a”

babbcbdbebfbgbhbibjbkblbmb

bnbobpbqbrbsbtbubvbwbxbybzb

b…b. b, b; b: b! b? b-b–b—b’s b”

cacbccdcecfcgchcicjckclcmc

cncocpcqcrcsctcucvcwcxcyczc

c…c. c, c; c: c! c? c-c–c—c’s c”

dadbdcdddedfdgdhdidjdkdldmd

dndodpdqdrdsdtdudvdwdxdydzd

d…d. d, d; d: d! d? d-d–d—d’s d”

eaebecedeeefegeheiejekeleme

eneoepeqereseteuevewexeyeze

e…e. e, e; e: e! e? e-e–e—e’s e”

fafbfcfdfefffgfhfifjfkflfmf

fnfofpfqfrfsftfufvfwfxfyfzf

f…f. f, f; f: f! f? f-f–f—f’s f”

gagbgcgdgegfggghgigjgkglgmg

gngogpgqgrgsgtgugvgwgxgygzg

g…g. g, g; g: g! g? g-g–g—g’s g”

hahbhchdhehfhghhhihjhkhlhmh

hnhohphqhrhshthuhvhwhxhyhzh

h…h. h, h; h: h! h? h-h–h—h’s h”

iaibicidieifigihiiijikiliminioipiqirisiti

iuiviwixiyizi i…i. i, i; i: i! i? i-i–i—i’s i”

jajbjcjdjejfjgjhjijjjkjljmjjnjojpjqjrjsjtjujvj

jwjxjyjzj j…j. j, j; j: j! j? j-j–j—j’s j”

kakbkckdkekkfkgkhkikjkkklkmknkok

kpkqkrksktkukkvkwkxkykzk

k…k. k, k; k: k! k? k-k–k—k’s k”

lalblcldlelflglhliljlklllmlnlolplqlrlsltlulvl

lwlxlylzl l…l. l, l; l: l! l? l-l–l—l’s l”

mambmcmdmemfmgmhmimjmkm

mlmmmnmompmqmrmsmtmumvm

mwmxmymzm’s m”

m…m. m, m; m: m! m? m-m–m—m

nanbncndnenfngnhninjnknlnmn

nnnonpnqnrnsntnunvnwnxnynzn

n…n. n, n; n: n! n? n-n–n—n’s n”

oaobocodoeofogohoiojokolomo

onooopoqorosotouovowoxoyozo

o…o. o, o; o: o! o? o-o–o—o’s o”

papbpcpdpepfpgphpipjpkplpmp

pnpopppqprpsptpupvpwpxpypzp

p…p. p, p; p: p! p? p-p–p—p’s p”

qaqbqcqdqeqfqgqhqiqjqkqlqmq

qnqoqpqqqrqsqtquqvqwqxqyqzq

q…q. q, q; q: q! q? q-q–q—q’s q”

rarbrcrdrerfrgrhrirjrkrlrmr

rnrorprqrrrsrtrurvrwrxryrzr

r…r. r, r; r: r! r? r-r–r—r’s r”

sasbscsdsesfsgshsisjskslsms

snsospsqsrssstsusvswsxsyszs

s…s. s, s; s: s! s? s-s–s—s’s s”

tatbtctdtetftgthtitjtktltmt

tntotptqtrtstttutvtwtxtytzt

t…t. t, t; t: t! t? t-t–t—t’s t”

uaubucudueufuguhuiujukulumu

unuoupuqurusutuuuvuwuxuyuzu

u…u. u, u; u: u! u? u-u–u—u’s u”

vavbvcvdvevfvgvhvivjvkvlvmv

vnvovpvqvrvsvtvuvvvwvxvyvzv

v…v. v, v; v: v! v? v-v–v—v’s v”

wawbwcwdwewfwgwhwiwjwkw

wlwmwnwowpwqwrwswtwuwvw

wwxwywzw’s w”

w…w. w, w; w: w! w? w-w–w—w

xaxbxcxdxexfxgxhxixjxkxlxmxnx

xoxpxqxrxsxtxuxvxwxxxyxzx

x…x. x, x; x: x! x? x-x–x—x’s x”

yaybycydyeyfygyhyiyjykylymyny

yoypyqyrysytyuyvywyxyyyzy

y…y. y, y; y: y! y? y-y–y—y’s y”

zazbzczdzezfzgzhzizjzkzlzmznz

zozpzqzzrzsztzuzvzwzxzyzzz

z…z. z, z; z: z! z? z-z–z—z’s z”


UPPER & LOWER



Aaron Able Ache Advert

Aegis Aft Age Ahe Ails 

Ajar Akin Aloe Amish And

Aone Ape Aqua Are Ascot

Atlas Auto Avon Awe Axe 

Aye Azo Aí Aì Aî Aï

Band Bet Bing Bloat Bog

Bring Bumpy Byte Bí Bì Bî Bï

Carry Celar Cinthia Cope Crap 

Cult Cycle Cí Cì Cî Cï

Dark Demon Dingy Dope Dumb 

Dí Dì Dî Dï

Each Eels Einar Eons Euchre 

Ever Ewer Exit Eyes Eí Eì Eî Eï

Fact Fever Fire Fıne Font Framer 

Fur Fyrd Fähr Földer Fà Få Fál 

Fâl Fãl Fè Fé Fêl Fël Fíl Fìl Fîl Fïl 

Fól Fò Fôl Fõl Fúl Fù Fûl Fÿ Fünk 

Gayle Gentle Girl Gnome Gí Gì Gî Gï

Gonot Grinning Gulf Gwen Gyro 

Harder Help Hilton Honor Hunk

Hv Hymn Hí Hì Hî Hï

Ian Ieo Iggy Iillian Ion Iugia Iyaaa

Ií Iì Iî Iï 

Jacky Jester Jimmy Joint Junk  

Jí Jì Jî Jï

Kangaroo Keep Kill Kline

Kop Kudees Kwick Kva Kyle 

Kärn Köff Küdos Kì Kî Kï Kÿ

Lay Learned Listing Load Lung

Lw Lynch 

Mail Meal Minx Mode Music 

Myth Mí Mì Mî Mï

Nail Next Nile Nooky Numb 

Ní Nì Nî Nï

Oatmeal Oer Offer Ogor Oink Oolong 

Out Over Oyster Oí Oì Oî Oï

Painter Peal Pile Pıne Pjb Plaster

Pointer Printer Putt Pygmy Päl Pöl

Pünk Pál Pà Pâl Pãl På Pél Pè 

Pêl Píl Pì Pîl Pïl Pól Pò Pôl

Põl Púl Pù Pûl Pÿ

Qanat Qels Qix Qon Quest 

Qí Qì Qî Qï

Rate Red Right Royal Run 

Ryal Rän Röad Rüng

Rí Rì Rî Rï

Sallie Scuzz Sensation Shell Sink 

Smelly Snowball Soul Spoke Sqish 

Stoner Sung Svelt Swap Symantic

Sí Sì Sî Sï

Tail Teal Them Timer Tıme 

Toll Trustee Tsing Tumbs Twizzlers

Typing Täp Törn Tüff Tál Tà Tâl 

Tãl Tål Tél Tè Têl Tël Tíl Tì Tîl 

Tïl Tól Tò Tôl Tõl Túl Tù Tûl Tÿ

Uarco Ue Ui Umbrella Under Uo 

Upper Ursula User Utterly Uu Uv 

Uwe Uí Uì Uî Uï

Vain Vc Veto Vine Vıne Vlad

Vow Vroor Vs Vulgar Vying 

Vämping Vöter Vál Và Vâl Vãl Vå 

Vél Vè Vêl Vë Víl Vìl Vîl Vïl Vól 

Vò Vôl Vö Võl Vúl Vù Vûl Vü Vÿ

Wale Wet What Window Wınd 

Wm Wow Wren Wsa Wte Wud 

Wxe Wynde Wäne Wál Wà Wâl

Wãl Wå Wél Wè Wêl Wël Wíl 

Wìl Wîl Wïl Wól Wò Wôl Wöl 

Wÿ Wõl Wúl Wù Wûl Wül

Xanth Xelo Xi Xo Xu Xylo 

Xál Xà Xâ Xä Xã Xå Xé Xè

Xê Xë Xíl Xìl Xîl Xïl Xó Xò Xô 

Xö Xõ Xú Xù Xû Xü Xå Xÿ

Yale Yddes Yearling Yicks Yıeld 

Yoyo Ypring Yrs Ys Yuck 

Yviye Yz Yá Yà Yâ Yä Yã Yå 

Yé Yè Yê Yë Yí Yì Yî Yï Yó 

Yò Yô Yö Yõ Yú Yù Yû Yü  

Zanzabar Zellis Zion Zope Zulu 

Zyle Zí Zì Zî Zï


SIDE BEARINGS


HIHOH


HAHBHCHDHEH

OAOBOCODOEO

HFHGHHHIHJH

OFOGOHOIOJO

HKHLHMHNHOHPHON

OKOLOMONOOPO

HQUHRHSHTHUH

OQOROSOTOUO

HVHWHXHYHZH

OVOWOXOYOZO

HÌHÍHÏHÎHHÆHŒH

HØHHÇHOÇO


HIHOH  Hillolih

nanbncndnenfngno

oaobocodoeofogo

nhninjnknlnmnnn

ohoiojokolomono

nonpnqnrnsntnun

ooopoqorosotouo

nvnwnxnynzn

ovowoxoyozo

nßnænœnønnçn

oßoæoœoøooço

líll lìll lîll lïll lildibıb

√oﬁlloﬂilo≠o¶o∞H¬


IOIH! IOIH? f! f? ¡H! ¿H?

«n»«o»‹n›‹o›

H&HO&O{H}H

H•HO•OH@HªHº

H⁄H‚H„H™H®H©H

H·H O·O`´˘¨ˆ˜¯ˇ˙˚¸˝˛ˆ

“HIOH” 


IOIH. H, H: H;

O.O,O:O;‘O’

‘HIH’S “HIH” ‘H’ 

(H)[H]{H}(O)[O]

H/H\H

H£0H$0H0¢Hƒ7H¥7H

H*H†H‡H§H

IOH-HO-O

H–HO–O

H—HO—O

1'1"0°H#7#0H

00%00‰H…H

H=H+H±H

H0H1H2H3H4H5H

H6H7H8H9HOH

00110121314151

16171819122

202122324252

2627282930


CAPS & PUNCTUATION


H…H. H: H, H; H! H?

A…A. A: A, A; A! A?

B…B. B: B, B; B! B?

C…C. C: C, C; C! C?

D…D. D: D, D; D! D?

E…E. E: E, E; E! E?

F…F. F: F, F; F! F?

G…G. G: G, G; G! G?

H…H. H: H, H; H! H?

I…I. I: I, I; I! I?

J…J. J: J, J; J! J?

K…K. K: K, K; K! K?

L…L. L: L, L; L! L?

M…M. M: M, M; M! M?

N…N. N: N, N; N! N?

O…O. O: O, O; O! O?

P…P. P: P, P; P! P?

Q…Q. Q: Q, Q; Q! Q?

R…R. R: R, R; R! R?

S…S. S: S, S; S! S?

T…T. T: T, T; T! T?

U…U. U: U, U; U! U?

V…V. V: V, V; V! V?

W…W. W: W, W; W! W?

X…X. X: X, X; X! X?

Y…Y. Y: Y, Y; Y! Y?

Z…Z. Z: Z, Z; Z! Z?


H-H–H—H’S “H” ‘H’

A-A–A—AA’S “A”

B-B–B—BB’S “B”

C-C–C—CC’S “C”

D-D–D—DD’S “D”

E-E–E—EE’S “E”

F-F–F—FF’S “F”

G-G–G—GG’S “G”

H-H–H—HH’S “H”

I-I–I—II’S “I”

J-J–J—JJ’S “J”

K-K–K—KK’S “K”

L-L–L—LL’S “L”

M-M–M—MM’S “M”

N-N–N—NN’S “N”

O-O–O—OO’S “O”

P-P–P—PP’S “P”

Q-Q–Q—QQ’S “Q”

R-R–R—RR’S “R”

S-S–S—SS’S “S”

T-T–T—TT’S “T”

U-U–U—UU’S “U”

V-V–V—VV’S “V”

W-W–W—WW’S “W”

X-X–X—XX’S “X”

Y-Y–Y—YY’S “Y”

Z-Z–Z—ZZ’S “Z”


LOWER CASE

& PUNCTUATION


H…H. H! H?

l…l. l: l, l; l! l?

a…a. a: a, a; a! a?

b…b. b: b, b; b! b?

c…c. c: c, c; c! c?

d…d. d: d, d; d! d?

e…e. e: e, e; e! e?

f…f. f: f, f; f! f?

g…g. g: g, g; g! g?

h…h. h: h, h; h! h?

i…i. i: i, i; i! i?

j…j. j: j, j; j! j?

k…k. k: k, k; k! k?

l…l. l: l, l; l! l?

m…m. m: m, m; m! m?

n…n. n: n, n; n! n?

o…o. o: o, o; o! o?

p…p. p: p, p; p! p?

q…q. q: q, q; q! q?

r…r. r: r, r; r! r?

s…s. s: s, s; s! s?

t…t. t: t, t; t! t?

u…u. u: u, u; u! u?

v…v. v: v, v; v! v?

w…w. w: w, w; w! w?

x…x. x: x, x; x! x?

y…y. y: y, y; y! y?

z…z. z: z, z; z! z?


H-H–H—H’S “H” ‘H’

l-l–l—ll’s “l” ‘l’

o-o–o—oso’s “o”

a-a–a—asa’s “a”

b-b–b—bsb’s “b”

c-c–c—csc’s “c”

d-d–d—dsd’s “d”

e-e–e—ese’s “e”

f-f–f—fsf’s “f” 

g-g–g—gsg’s “g”

h-h–h—hsh’s “h”

i-i–i—isi’s “i”

j-j–j—jsj’s “j”

k-k–k—ksk’s “k”

l-l–l—lsl’s “l”

m-m–m—msm’s “m”

n-n–n—nsn’s “n”

o-o–o—oso’s “o”

p-p–p—psp’s “p”

q-q–q—qsq’s “q”

r-r–r—rsr’s “r”

s-s–s—sss’s “s”

t-t–t—tst’s “t”

u-u–u—usu’s “u”

v-v–v—vsv’s “v”

w-w–w—wsw’s “w”

x-x–x—xsx’s “x”

y-y–y—ysy’s “y”

z-z–z—zsz’s “z”


INCIDENTALS


A* B* C* D* E* 

F* G* H* I* J* K*

L* M* N* O* P* 

Q* R* S* T* U* 

V* W* X* Y* Z*

a* b* c* d* e* 

f* g* h* i* j* k*

l* m* n* o* p* 

q* r* s* t* u* 

v* w* x* y* z*


f.* f,* f;* f:*

r.* r,* r;* r:*

v.* v,* v;* v:*

w.* w,* w;* w:*

y.* y,* y;* y:*     

T.* T,* T;* T:*

V.* V,* V;* V:*

W.* W,* W;* W:*

Y.* Y,* Y;* Y:*

f.” f,” f.’ f,’

r.” r,” r.’ r,’ 

v.” v,” v.’ v,’ 

w.” w,” w.’ w,’ 

y.” y,” y.’ y,’   

T.” T,” T.’ T,’  

V” V.” V,” V.’ V,’ 

W.” W,” W.’ W,’ 

Y.” Y,” Y.’ Y,’ 

“…” ‘…’ “ ” 

“HIH!” !’ 

“HIH?” ?’ 


WE’D I’LL 

I’M TAM’O

WE’RE WE'VE

WHO’S WHAT'S

AIN’T I’VE

edWe’d I’d We’ll

I’m tam’omo 

we’rer who’s 

isn’t I’ve

‘A’ ‘E’ ‘J’ ‘O’ ‘T’ 

‘V’ ‘W’ ‘Y’ 

“A” “E” “J” 

“O” “T”

“V” “W” “Y” 


/A/B/C/D/E/F/

/G/H/I/J/K/L/ 

/M/N/O/P/Q/

/R/S/T/U/V/A 

/W/X/Y/Z/   

/a/b/c/d/e/f/ 

/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/

/n/o/p/q/r/s/ 

/t/u/v/w/x/y/z/ 

/0/1/2/3/4/

/5/6/7/8/9/



A™ A® B™ B® C™ C® 

D™ D® E™ E® F™ F®

G™ G® H™ H® I™ I®

J™ J® K™ K® L™ L® 

M™ M® N™ N® O™ O®

P™ P® Q™ Q® R™ R®

S™ S® T™ T® U™ U® 

V™ V® W™ W® X™ X®

Y™ Y® Z™ Z® 

a™ a® b™ b® c™ c® 

d™ d® e™ e® f™ f®

g™ g® h™ h® i™ i®

j™ j® k™ k® l™ l® 

m™ m® n™ n® o™ o®

p™ p® q™ q® r™ r®

s™ s® t™ t® u™ u® 

v™ v® w™ w® x™ x® 

y™ y® z™ z®


001020304050

0607080900

101121314151

16171819100

202122324252

26272829200

303132334353

36373839300

404142434454

46474849400

505152535455

56575859500

606162636465

6676869600

707172737475

7677879700

808182838485

8687889800

909192939495

9697989900

(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)

(6)(7)(8)(9)(0)



$00 $10 $20 $30 $40 

$50 $60 $70 $80 $90 

£00 £10 £20 £30 £40 

£50 £60 £70 £80 £90 

ƒ00 ƒ10 ƒ20 ƒ30 ƒ40 

ƒ50 ƒ60 ƒ70 ƒ80 ƒ90

00¢ 11¢ 22¢ 33¢ 44¢

55¢ 66¢ 77¢ 88¢ 99¢



00% 0‰ 0-0.0,0…0° 

11% 1‰ 1-1.1,1…1°

00% 0‰ 0-0.0,0…0° 

12% 2‰ 2-2.2,2…2°

13% 3‰ 3-3.3,3…3°

11% 1‰ 1-1.1,1…1°

14% 4‰ 4-4.4,4…4°

15% 5‰ 5-5.5,5…5°

16% 6‰ 6-6.6,6…6°

11% 1‰ 1-1.1,1…1°

17% 7‰ 7-7.7,7…7°

18% 8‰ 8-8.8,8…8°

19% 9‰ 9-9.9,9…9°
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the [`kerntest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kerntest) package might be what you are looking for:

> This class makes it easy to gen­er­ate ta­bles that show many dif­fer­ent kern­ing pairs of an ar­bi­trary font, us­able by LaTeX. It shows the kern­ing val­ues that are used in the font by de­fault.